# Convert/Wrap Swift struct as NSValue for CAAnimation purposes?

Tags: swift, struct, swift2, caanimation, nsvalue

I have a custom `CALayer` subclass that draws a circular arc. It looks something like:

```
class ArcLayer: CALayer {
    var strokeColor:UIColor = UIColor.blackColor() { didSet { self.setNeedsDisplay() }}
    var strokeWidth:CGFloat = 1.0 { didSet { self.setNeedsDisplay() }}
    var strokeCap:CGLineCap = .Butt { didSet { self.setNeedsDisplay() }}
    var startRadians:CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { self.setNeedsDisplay() }}
    var sweepRadians:CGFloat = Tau  { didSet { self.setNeedsDisplay() }}

    // other init's omitted for brevity 

    override init(layer: AnyObject) {
        super.init(layer: layer)
        if let layer = layer as? ArcLayer {
            self.strokeColor = layer.strokeColor
            self.strokeWidth = layer.strokeWidth
            self.strokeCap = layer.strokeCap
            self.startRadians = layer.startRadians
            self.sweepRadians = layer.sweepRadians
        }
    }

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
        ...
    }

    override class func needsDisplayForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
        return key == "startRadians" || key == "sweepRadians" || super.needsDisplayForKey(key)
    }
}
```

I'm using a custom subclass, because while the `path` of a `CAShapeLayer` is animatable, it does not animate in the way you would expect the arc to rotate around. The above works. Animations to the start/sweep produce the desired effect.

I want to change it though. I have an `Angle` struct (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32873601/999530)) which I would rather use than the raw radian CGFloat value. Changing the type of those two vars to `Angle` compiles fine. And the original display works too (after making the appropriate conversions/extractions from the `Angle` vars). THE PROBLEM is being able to animate those vars now. Where as before I might have written some code like:

```
let sweep = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "sweepRadians")
sweep.fromValue = 0.0 // raw radians value
sweep.toValue = Tau // raw radians value for one rotation
sweep.duration = 10.seconds
sweep.repeatCount = 0
self.blueRing.addAnimation(sweep, forKey: "sweepRadians")
```

I can't just change those to `Angle` values:

```
sweep.fromValue = Angle(raw: 0, unit: .Rotations)
sweep.toValue = Angle(raw: 0, unit: .Rotations)
```

That results in a

```
cannot assign value of type 'Angle' to type of 'AnyObject?'
```

I'm hoping that the solution is that I need to somehow convert/wrap my `Angle` values as NSValue objects? Is that indeed correct? Can it be done? How so?

I really like Swift, but the corner cases where it intersects with Objc can be really confusing.

Answer (score 4):

`Angle` is a struct, which does not conform to `AnyObject`. In order to conform to `AnyObject`, you need to change it to a class, or wrap it into a class like `Box`:

```
final class Box<T> {
    let value: T
    init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }
}
```

That said, this is unlikely to work. `CABasicAnimation` has special knowledge about how to [interpolate specific things](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html):

- integers and doubles
- CGRect, CGPoint, CGSize, and CGAffineTransform structures
- CATransform3D data structures
- CGColor and CGImage references

I don't believe there's any way to add to this list. I don't believe you can use `CABasicAnimation` to interpolate arbitrary types. You need to animate from a number to a number, so that's going to be basically the code you have above.

Of course you can make `sweepRadians` be a computed property that just forwards to `sweep`, and you could animate from `Degrees(0).rawRadians` to `Degrees(360).rawRadians`. So you can get most of the practical benefits you want; just not without manually converting to a number at some point.

Now if this is Mac, you can subclass `NSAnimation` and build your own animator that can do this. See [CABasicAnimation and custom types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531314/cabasicanimation-and-custom-types) for discussion of that. But there's no `NSAnimation` on iOS, and I don't believe you can subclass `CAAnimation` in the same way. There's no "progress" delegate method on `CAAnimation`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `init(pointer pointer: UnsafePointer<Void>)`of `NSValue`. You may obtain the pointer to your `Angle` instance using `func withUnsafePointer<T, Result>(inout arg: T, @noescape _ body: UnsafePointer<T> throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result` (see http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/func/withUnsafePointer/ for reference). 
P.S. The idea of passing NSValue-wrapped things to Core Animation is a working technique in general. It's still unclear if CA will unwrap Angle though. Good luck.