# how to convert custom Objc struct to NSValue in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, struct, nsvalue

I define a custom struct in Objc

```
typedef struct {

    int a; 

    int b; 

} MyStruct;
```

In Objc I can convert the struct to NSValue use

```
MyStruct struct = {0};
NSValue *value = [NSValue value:&struct withObjCType:@encode(MyStruct)];
```

But how can I do this in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert/Wrap Swift struct as NSValue for CAAnimation purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893429/convert-wrap-swift-struct-as-nsvalue-for-caanimation-purposes)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your Objective-C code add a function like

```
const char * __nonnull getMyStructOCT() {
    return @encode(MyStruct);
}
```

and make it available to Swift code via a bridging header.  Then in your Swift code you can do, for example, the following:

```
let myStructOCT = getMyStructOCT()  // can then reuse myStructOCT over and over
var s = MyStruct(a: 111, b: 222)
let v = NSValue(bytes: &s, objCType: myStructOCT)
```

If you want to retrieve the value:

```
var s1 = MyStruct()
v.getValue(&s1)  // s1 now has your value
```